# Can I install laminate flooring one room at a time?

Tags: laminate-floor

I am thinking about install laminate flooring for my second floor. There are 3 rooms (master, 2 kids rooms) on second floor. The laminate covers all the second floor excepts there are two transition moldings at the doors of two kids rooms.

First, can I move all the furnitures from master room to two kids rooms first, then install the laminate flooring with the same layout up toward the hallway (stop right at the transition molding at the kids rooms). After I finish the master room and hallway laminate floor, then I move all furnitures from kids rooms to master room and work on two rooms' floor? Is this recommended?

Comment: Why do you want to make the new laminate stick tightly with the subfloor?

Comment: to minimize any possible gap in between?

Comment: Not sure what gap you're referring to. Gap between the floor and subfloor? Gap somewhere else?

Comment: the possible gaps between laminate and subfloor due to slight uneven flatness of subfloor. (<3/16 " )

Comment: Oh, you'll want to solve that.  Laminare doesn't cover flaws in subfloors. It fails due to them.

Comment: Yes you can. Depending on the type, if it recommends a slip poly underlay , use it to prevent squeaks.